# What would be my tenant URL and where in the admin center I need to consent access requested?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, graph-api, tenant

I have following ShareGate PowerShell script. I need to connect to tenant URL.

Is that `portal.office.com`?

Also which admin center I need to connect to grant ShareGate Graph API access?

```
# Connect to the source and destination tenants
$source = Connect-Tenant -Domain sourcetenant
$destination = Connect-Tenant -Domain destinationtenant

# Read the CSV file with team names
$teamsData = Import-Csv -Path "teamslist.csv"

foreach ($teamData in $teamsData) {
    $sourceTeamName = $teamData.SourceTeam
    $targetTeamName = $teamData.TargetTeam

    # Get the source team
    $team = Get-Team -Name $sourceTeamName -Tenant $source

    # Copy the entire team (including channels) to the destination tenant
    Copy-Team -Team $team -DestinationTenant $destination

    # Optional: If you want to copy only specific channels within the team
    $channels = Get-TeamChannel -Team $team
    Copy-Team -Team $team -Channel $channels -DestinationTenant $destination
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Microsoft 365 tenant URL is NOT `portal.office.com`. You are using:

```
$destination = Connect-Tenant -Domain destinationtenant
```

Where `destinationtenant` is the part before `.sharepoint.com` in your SharePoint tenant URL.

**Example**: If you have your SharePoint site URL like `https://mytenantdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/HR`, your tenant domain will be `mytenantdomain`. So, you will have to use the command like:

```
$destination = Connect-Tenant -Domain mytenantdomain
```

Follow below documentations for granting admin consent to use ShareGate tools:

1. [Microsoft administrative permissions](https://documentation.sharegate.com/hc/articles/115000642708-Microsoft-administrative-permissions)
2. [How can a global admin grant consent to the Azure ShareGate migration tool app for all users?](https://documentation.sharegate.com/hc/articles/360033358471-How-can-a-global-admin-grant-consent-to-the-Azure-ShareGate-migration-tool-app-for-all-users)